# Customer registration problem. Page reload after submit

Tags: magento-1.8, nginx, multidomain

I have two magento websites in domain and subdomain like test.com and test.test.com.

In Domain website and admin panel works fine.
But In Subdomain website the customer registration not done.After submit it only reload the registration page. I also enable log and check the log file but there is no error.

Also In Subdomain admin panel.I can login and view the admin panel dashboard.I can also view pages and blocks. But I can't create new page and update the page.After click on save it simply reload the page.

I use nginx server.I didn't change nginx server configuration after creating subdomain.

Please give me suggestion.I face this problem since last week.

Comment: which version of magento are you using please @Ashik?

Comment: my magento version is : magento 1.8.0.0

Answer (score 2):

I had that issue some times ago, it is related to form key.

For some reason form key is missing in your template under `persistent/customer/form/register.phtml` and in your customer `persistent/customer/form/login.phtml`

put this code under your form

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

This post will help you 
http://www.hellothemes.com/blog/fix-customer-login-update-cart-quantity-magento-1-8-1/

Answer (score 1):

If using the latest version of magento (1.9.2.2) the security patch is included which adds a formkey to the following file:
`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`

If you have overridden this in your theme you will need to add the following code in below the opening `<form>` tag:

`<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>`

Hope this helps,

Josh

Comment: Sir, I also tried with adding <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?> below form tag then also its not work.I'm stuck with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a theme i've installed.

And adding the form key solved my problem, but i have added as a hidden  to the `register.phtml` as follows:

File Path:

```
app/design/frontend/default/theme_folder/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
```

Line added after the opening `<form>`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check cookies domain under core config data database table.this is something relating to cookies. Can you clear cookies and open your subdomain (not main domain), and try to register? It should register successfully